# Dark regions of render looks distorted / blurry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

[image]

Rendered with cycles with 2048 samples and 0.04 noise threshold

What are the causes for these distortion?

Besides adding additional lighting around them, are there any methods of improving these regions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You posted a heavily compressed image in Jpeg format which introduces compression artifacts of its own. We can't really tell what we are looking at, if it is the direct output of rendering, sampling noise, render artifacts, too much denoise, or other issues. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so if the linked post doesn't solve your issue show us your render settings and preferences and clarify what we are looking at.